In cooking does KCl draw water from food "same as" NaCl?
For medicinal/health reasons, cardiac and high blood pressure in particular, Potassium Chloride (KCl) is often used in place of Sodium Chloride (NaCl) AKA table salt for food purposes. It is offered as a 1:1 substitute, i.e. use KCl the same as NaCl in cooking. Taste wise, it is (basically) same and produces the same results, so they are essentially interchangeable for taste. This substitution has a dual beneficial effect — first off, it lowers serum Na+ levels and it increases serum K+ levels, both of which are independently cardio-protective.
What about other chemical uses in cooking?

Many recipes salt items before cooking to "draw water out" of vegetables before cooking them.
In baking you add salt to yeast ferments to control (slow down) the fermentation process of the yeast.
Additionally salted foods were one of the first long term stored items.

Would KCl work same as/better/worse than NaCl in these instances?
My focus is not health or taste concerns those are well known. My questions are on the chemical implications for food preparation and storage. I have found nothing on this with multiple searches.

Most "salts" will dehydrate but their taste may be horrible. NaCl is not unique.

I have never heard of such a careless potassium intake by replacing salt in cooking and food processing.
Particularly, using KCl for food conservation can be very dangerous, as a human body is much more sensitive toward acute potassium overdosing, compared to sodium, what is further boosted if a person has some cardiac or kidney issues. // For water drawing, there would be needed about 30% KCl more by weight // KCl is about 1/3 less salty than NaCl by weight and has reportedly bitter undertaste (can vary as some taste perception is genetic dependent).

it increases serum K+ levels, both of which are independently cardio-protective. - this is dangerously just one part of truth, as the other part is that high levels can cause sudden cardiac death. // K intake from natural food K content is safe, but uncontrolled use of K supplements can cause acute hyperkalemia. The symptoms may develop quickly, can be lethal and affect various body systems, particularly the muscular, cardiac, and nervous systems.

It might be a more appropriate question at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ Note also that questions regarding personal medical advice are off topic. And it is always good to cite supporting references that provide details (see Poutnik's comments).

See e.g. Hyperkalemia - National Library of Medicine //  While mild hyperkalemia is usually asymptomatic, high potassium levels may cause life-threatening cardiac arrhythmias, muscle weakness, or paralysis. Symptoms usually develop at higher levels, 6.5 mEq/L to 7 mEq/L, but the rate of change is more important than the numerical value.

IMHO, it is rather topic for medicine than cooking, to prevent serious mistakes...

Life-threatening hyperkalemia from nutritional supplements: uncommon or undiagnosed?  // Abstract quote:  "... We present two unique cases of near-fatal hyperkalemia from nutritional supplements containing potassium. The first case was due to salt-substitute intake ..."

Was attempting to keep medical out of it per Americian Heart Assoc (and numerous others) - "Use of potassium-enriched salt substitutes, in which the sodium chloride in traditional salt is partially replaced with potassium chloride (KCl), is a potential BP-lowering strategy under consideration by several countries ..."  "Salt substitutes can reduce dietary sodium intake and increase potassium intake at the population level when manufactured foods are reformulated..."  full report here - https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/full/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.119.13241

All depends on amounts and speed how K transfers to blood serum. Salting a food by NaCl enriched by KCl is perfectly OK. But there is need to avoid extremes like KCl food conservation where the food can contain up to several % of KCl..

Unfortunately it appears non-clinical theorists are out thinking the clinicians with real world experience. There is ample evidence of the safety of KCl for dietary use, including it being sold in retail groceries for over 50 years and it is endorsed by major medical groups including AHA, AMA & WHO as per my attached paper.  As stated in my original post my question was never about the effects in the human (which is well documented), but on the chemical impact for recipes, as indicated by the 3 specific questions.  It has been diverted it off point despite my clearly phrasing away from that.
